# Nokogiri and Xpath: find all text between two tags

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm not sure if it's a matter of syntax or differences in versions but I can't seem to figure this out.  I want to take data that is inside a (non-closing) `td` from the `h2` tag to the `h3` tag.  Here is what the HTML would look like.

```
<td valign="top" width="350">
    <br><h2>NameIWant</h2><br>
    <br>Town<br>

    PhoneNumber<br>
    <a href="mailto:emailIwant@nowhere.com" class="links">emailIwant@nowhere.com</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://websiteIwant.com" class="links">websiteIwant.com</a>
    <br><br>    
    <br><img src="images/spacer.gif"/><br>

    <h3><b>I want to stop before this!</b></h3>
    Lorem Ipsum Yadda Yadda<br>
    <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="20" height="11" alt=""/><br>
    <td width="25">
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" border="0" width="20" height="8" alt=""/>
        <td valign="top" width="200"><img src="images/spacer.gif"/>
            <br>
            <br>

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"/>205"&gt;<tr><td>
                <a href="http://dontneedthis.com">
                </a></td></tr><br>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="200">
            ...
```

The `<td valign>` doesn't close until the very bottom of the page which I think might be why I'm having problems.

My Ruby code looks like:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.url.com"))

content = @doc.css('//td[valign="top"] [width="350"]')

name = content.xpath('//h2').text
puts name // Returns NameIwant

townNumberLinks = content.search('//following::h2')
puts content // Returns <h2> NameIWant </h2>
```

As I understand it following syntax should "Selects everything in the document after the closing tag of the current node".  If I try to use `preceding` like:

```
townNumberLinks = content.search('//preceding::h3')
// I get: <h3><b>I want to stop before this!</b></h3>
```

Hope I made it clear what I'm trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not trivial. In the context of the nodes you selected (the `td`), to get everything *between* two elements, you need to perform an *intersection* of these two sets:

1. Set *A*: All the nodes *preceding* the *first* `h3`: `//h3[1]/preceding::node()`
2. Set *B*: All the nodes *following* the *first* `h2`: `//h2[1]/following::node()`

To perform an intersection, you can use the *[Kaysian method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e108)* (after [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay), who proposed it). The basic formula is:

```
A[count(.|B) = count(B)]
```

Applying it to your sets, as defined above, where *A* = `//h3[1]/preceding::node()`, and *B* = `//h2[1]/following::node()`, we have:

```
//h3[1]/preceding::node()[ count( . | //h2[1]/following::node()) = count(//h2[1]/following::node()) ]
```

which will select *all elements and text nodes* starting with the first `<br>` after the `</h2>` tag, to the whitespace text node after the last `<br>`, just before the next `<h3>` tag.

You can easily select *just the text nodes between `h2` and `h3`* replacing `node()` for `text()` in the expression. This one will return all text nodes (including whitespace and linebreaks) between the two headers:

```
//h3[1]/preceding::text()[ count( . | //h2[1]/following::text()) = count(//h2[1]/following::text()) ]
```

Comment: You could also put the selectors for the two sets into (Ruby) variables and interpolate the query – it could make it cleaer. Another way to get the intersection would be to make two separate queries and find the intersection of the two resulting node-sets Ruby with `&`.

Comment: @matt You could add that one. It would also be a very interesting answer.

Comment: This seems to do the trick, thank you very much!  Also thanks for the Kaysian reference; it clears things up a bit for me.

Answer (score 1):

Find all elements preceding the first `<h3>` in the cell, than retrieve all preceding siblings not having an `<h2>` tag as preceding sibling. Replace `//td` by the XPath expression to retrieve exactly this table cell.

```
//td/h3[1]/preceding-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h2]
```

Comment: I tried using this one but it simply returns '' I am using    @doc.xpath('//h3[1]/preceding-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h2]').to_xml