# Traverse elements that aren't children between two elements with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I'm trying to figure out the best way to select `div` elements that match a css class between two other `div` elements. Here's some sample HTML of what I'm working with:

```
<div class="date">
  <span>Today</span>
</div>
<div class="random"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="random"></div>
<div class="date">
  <span>Tomorrow</span>
</div>
```

What I want is to basically return the `divs` whose class is "preferred" between the `divs` with "date" class.

I can grab my starting point with something like:

```
doc.at("span:contains('Today')").parent
```

However, I'm not sure the best way to get its `next_elements` based on `class` up until the next `div.date`.

Comment: See the link above. If you don't find a way to use it in your question, tell me and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Are all elements children of the first `div`? If not, please fix your code (close the tags appropriately) so that the structure is reflected correctly (maybe you should have a `</div>` after each `</span>`)

Comment: Looking at that now, @helderdarocha. Also, thanks for the tip on HTML. I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm applying the *[Kaysian method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e108)* for obtaining the *intersection* of a set (as described in the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193807/nokogiri-and-xpath-to-find-all-text-between-h2-and-h3-tags) of this question) in the context of your specific scenario (and not considering any other external context which you didn't include in your question).

You need to define two sets:

1. A: `//div[preceding-sibling::div[@class='date']]` (all `div` elements which have a preceding sibling `div` of the *date* class.)
2. B: `//div[following-sibling::div[@class='date']]` (all `div` elements which have a following sibling `div` of the *date* class.)

The *intersection* of those two sets is the solution to your problem. The formula of the Kaysian method is: `A [ count(. | B) = count(B) ]`. Applying that to your problem, the result you need is:

```
//div[preceding-sibling::div[@class='date']][count( . | //div[following-sibling::div[@class='date']] ) = count(//div[following-sibling::div[@class='date']] ) ]
```

This will select the following elements:

```
<div class="random"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="preferred"></div>
<div class="random"></div>
```

If you apply this expression *in a global context* where there are *other* `<div class="date">` elements, you will have to adapt it and change your sets so that they uniquely identify the bordering elements.