# How can I get the count of elements between elements of another class?

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to get the count of rows between the first category header and the second category header to use in a for loop as an increment. Here is an example of the html:

```
<div class="datagrid-ready" range="0:49" chunk-id="0.0" style="width:100%;height:2220px;" enabled="true">    
    <div class="categoryHeader" template="group" row-id="0">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="1">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="2">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="3">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="4">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="5">...</div>
    <div class="categoryHeader" template="group" row-id="6">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="7">...</div>
    <div class="categoryHeader"  template="group" row-id="8">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="9">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="10">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="11">...</div>
    <div class="categoryHeader" template="group" row-id="12">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="13">...</div>
    <div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="14">...</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have put together so far (obviously it doesn't work):

```
final int noItemsIn1stCat = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[contains(@class,'productTableRow')]")).size();
```

I am at a loss on how to get `5` into `noItemsIn1stCat`.

Would it be easier or more reliable to use a css selector?

I am new to java and selenium, so any help would be entirely appreciated!

Comment: Your divs don't have closing tags. Are they actually siblings or are they nested?

Comment: You can obtain those elements calculating an intersection. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247331/traverse-elements-that-arent-children-between-two-elements-with-nokogiri/24248014#24248014 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193807/nokogiri-and-xpath-find-all-text-between-two-tags/24194326#24194326

Comment: If at all possible, I'd recommend you to talk to Devs and ask them to restructure the divs in a smarter and more testable way, i.e. nesting .productTableRow in .categoryHeader. E.g.: <div class="categoryHeader"> <div class="productTableRow"></div> <div class="productTableRow"></div> </div>

Comment: Sorry, I copied from Firebug with the divs collapsed to simplify the question. The datagrid-ready div is a parent div of all the following divs. (They do have closing tags that were not visible when collapsed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node-set containing sibling elements between two other siblings can be obtained calculating the *intersection* of two sets. *Set A*: the set of elements that are *following siblings* of the first element, with *Set B*: the set of elements that are *preceding siblings* of the last element.

You can use the [*Kaysian method*](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e108) to select an intersection between two sets (see a more detailed explanation in the links I posted in the comments). The formula to obtain the intersection is:

```
SetA [ count( . | setB) = count( setB ) ]
```

Applying that to your problem, with:

```
SetA = //div[@class='datagrid-ready']
        /div[@class='categoryHeader'][1]
        /following-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow']
```

and

```
SetB = //div[@class='datagrid-ready']
        /div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]
        /preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow']
```

you have:

```
//div[@class='datagrid-ready']
  /div[@class='categoryHeader'][1]
  /following-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow']
    [ count( . | //div[@class='datagrid-ready']
                  /div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]
                  /preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'])
    = count( //div[@class='datagrid-ready']
              /div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]
              /preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'] ) ]
```

or in one line:

```
//div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'][count(.|//div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow']) = count( //div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'] ) ]
```

In your example, this expression will select these five nodes:

```
<div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="1">
<div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="2">
<div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="3">
<div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="4">
<div class="productTableRow" template="row" row-id="5">
```

To *count* the nodes, simply place the whole expression as an argument to the `count()` function:

```
count(//div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][1]/following-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'][count(.|//div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow']) = count( //div[@class='datagrid-ready']/div[@class='categoryHeader'][2]/preceding-sibling::div[@class='productTableRow'])])
```